# Chart.js Y-Axis labels on both sides

Tags: javascript, charts

I'm currently working with Chart.js on some quite large monitors and reading across the graphs to the left hand side to find values is becoming difficult even with the grid lines enabled. 
Is there a way to enable Y-axis labels on both sides of the graph pre v2.0?
My chart config is generated in a twig template and is as follows:

```
var LineData = {
 labels: [
  {% for label in labels %}
  " {{ label }} ",
  {% endfor %}
 ],
 datasets: [
  {
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",

    data: [
      {% for data in dataset1 %}
      "{{ data }}",
      {% endfor %}
    ]
  }, {
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",

    data: [
      {% for data in dataset2 %}
      "{{ data }}",
      {% endfor %}
    ]
  }
 ]

}
var options = {
 scaleFontColor: "#FFF",
 //String - Colour of the grid lines
 scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(155,155,155,0.3)",
 scaleOverride: true,
 scaleStepWidth: 10,
 scaleSteps: 25,
 scaleStartValue: 0,
 //Number - Width of the grid lines
 scaleGridLineWidth: 5
};
```